# Configure Azure Cache (<dataCacheClients>...) of WebRole in cscfg file?

Tags: azure-appfabric

Currently, I have my Azure Cache configuration

```
<dataCacheClients>
  <dataCacheClient name="default">
    ...
```

inside my Web.config of my Azure WebRole. I would like to be able to easily modify the Azure Cache settings after the cspkg package has been created, i.e. I would like to move the configuration into the cscfg file.

I don't think that's possible without hand-coding all the possible configuration options of Azure Caches (and then interpreting those options and setting the configuration programmatically in the DataCacheFactory). Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

in webrole `(RoleEntryPoint derived class)` onstart, you could overwrite `web.config` caching part with the relevant settings from your `.cscfg` file

also add eventhandler to the environment changing `(RoleEnvironment.Changing += RoleEnvironmentChanging;)` with `e.Cancel = true` so that the webrole restarts when ever you change `.cscfg` @ the management portal

Comment: Well yes, you can add all the dataCacheClient options to the cscfg as key/value-pairs somehow and then parse them out and manually do whatever you want. I would like to avoid the manual part.

Answer (score 0):

One walkarround is to rename your .cspkg file to .zip file. Then unzip the file and take a look to the files. You will find .cssx files (the larger files) representing each webrole / working role. rename to .zip and expand. Then you will find a "approot" folder. Your dlls, webconfig, etc are there. You can mess with the webconfig and zip+rename the way back.

It's not elegant at all, but sometimes is the best way to figure out what exactly are you publishing.

Comment: That was our first try at the time as well, but it didn't work, because included in that file is a checksum, and when you try to run (or deploy, I forgot at what step exactly) the modified .cspkg file Azure won't let you. I didn't implement it in the end, but I believe we are now using the cmd line tools for (re)packaging provided by MS and do that as part of our build process.

Comment: to be honest, I do that trick when I want to know exactly what am I deploying. I never tried to zip it again. Sorry it didn't help :(